# PinguyBuilder Broken On Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, ubiquity

I run Lubuntu 18.04 with Kernel 4.15 and keep experiencing an issue with PinguyBuilder. The initial iso is genereted without problems and also booting it works fine, but once I try to install I encounter an error.

After launching ubiquity, and selecting the install options "ubi-partman crashed with exit code 10" pops up.

After some googling I found a similar issue where a member recommended to add "/swapfile" to the excluded directories before making the iso, which I did, but the error persisted.

Here is the output of the syslog detailing the problem:

Apparently, there is a permission error while creating the main / directories, specifically /var. Any idea what could be causing this?

```
Jul 16 04:04:25 marc kernel: [  170.813514]  sda:
Jul 16 04:04:25 marc ubiquity[1507]: Step_before = stepKeyboardConf
Jul 16 04:04:25 marc ubiquity[1507]: switched to page prepare
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc ubiquity[1507]: debconffilter_done: ubi-prepare (current: ubi-prepare)
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc ubiquity[1507]: Step_before = stepPrepare
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc activate-dmraid: No Serial ATA RAID disks detected
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  175.780041] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 15205 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  175.828039] raid6: sse2x1   xor() 10622 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.260036] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 39344 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.308036] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 25335 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.308037] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 39344 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.308037] raid6: .... xor() 25335 MB/s, rmw enabled
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.308038] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.321425] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.359053] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Jul 16 04:04:30 marc kernel: [  176.398606] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.440960] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc partman:   No matching physical volumes found
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc partman:   Reading volume groups from cache.
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.496250] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.497254]  sda:
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.688766] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.689559]  sda:
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.702307] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  176.702998]  sda:
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  177.267814] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc kernel: [  177.318845] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc ubiquity[1507]: Device free not found in os-prober output
Jul 16 04:04:31 marc ubiquity[1507]: switched to page partman
Jul 16 04:04:34 marc dbus-daemon[4189]: [session uid=1000 pid=4187] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jul 16 04:04:37 marc kernel: [  182.976715] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Jul 16 04:04:37 marc kernel: [  182.977654]  sda:
Jul 16 04:04:41 marc ubiquity[1507]: debconffilter_done: ubi-partman (current: ubi-partman)
Jul 16 04:04:41 marc ubiquity[1507]: Step_before = stepPartAsk
Jul 16 04:04:41 marc ubiquity[1507]: switched to page timezone
Jul 16 04:04:42 marc ubiquity[1507]: Geoname lookup for "New York" failed: 2 Error resolving “geoname-lookup.ubuntu.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jul 16 04:04:42 marc kernel: [  187.784710] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Jul 16 04:04:42 marc kernel: [  187.785823]  sda: sda1 sda2
Jul 16 04:04:42 marc partman: mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: debian-installer/language preseeded to 'en' (seen: false)
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: debian-installer/country preseeded to 'US' (seen: true)
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: debian-installer/locale preseeded to 'en_US.UTF-8' (seen: true)
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Language = 'en'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: line=en;0;US;en_US.UTF-8;;console-setup
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Set debian-installer/language = 'en'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Default country = 'US'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Default locale = 'en_US.UTF-8'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Set debian-installer/consoledisplay = 'console-setup'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Set debian-installer/country = 'US'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: Set debian-installer/locale = 'en_US.UTF-8'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc localechooser: info: System locale (debian-installer/locale) = 'en_US.UTF-8'
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc ubiquity: /usr/lib/ubiquity/localechooser/localechooser: 910: [: C.UTF-8: unexpected operator
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc ubiquity[1507]: debconffilter_done: ubi-timezone (current: ubi-timezone)
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc ubiquity[1507]: Step_before = stepLocation
Jul 16 04:04:43 marc ubiquity[1507]: switched to page usersetup
Jul 16 04:04:47 marc ubiquity[1507]: debconffilter_done: ubi-usersetup (current: ubi-usersetup)
Jul 16 04:04:47 marc ubiquity[1507]: Step_before = stepUserInfo
Jul 16 04:04:49 marc kernel: [  195.289511] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jul 16 04:04:52 marc partman-swapfile: 2097152+0 records in
Jul 16 04:04:52 marc partman-swapfile: 2097152+0 records out
Jul 16 04:04:52 marc partman-swapfile: 2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied, 3.0585 s, 702 MB/s
Jul 16 04:04:55 marc kernel: [  201.235046] Adding 2097148k swap on /target/swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:2260988k SSFS
Jul 16 04:04:55 marc ubiquity: File descriptor 3 (pipe:[37521]) leaked on pvs invocation. Parent PID 6445: /bin/sh
Jul 16 04:04:56 marc ubiquity[1507]: debconffilter_done: ubiquity.components.partman_commit (current: None)
Jul 16 04:04:56 marc /install.py: keeping packages due to preseeding:
Jul 16 04:04:56 marc /install.py: keeping language packs for: en_US.UTF-8
Jul 16 04:04:56 marc ubiquity: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/target/var’: Permission denied
Jul 16 04:07:26 marc /install.py: Terminated ubiquity update process.
```

Comment: I have never used this tool, but its official site [recommends](https://pinguyos.com/2018/04/pinguy-builder-for-buntu-17-04-17-10-18-04-using-ubiquity/) not to use packages from repository. You should download package from their site.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this script (currently the version 5.1.8) for xubuntu-18.04.1.
The ISO-image created by the script is not bootable. But, you do have a good work-around for this problem.

You will find a directory named ISOTMP in the working directory of `pinguybuilder`. Just copy all those folders below ISOTMP to a freshly formatted bootable USB-Stick and do a `grub-install` to the USB-Stick.
Your system should boot from this without any problems.

A word of caution to all foreign-language users! You are well-advised to edit the `pinguybuilder` script before using it!
Extract the file `pinguybuilder` from the deb (it is in `/usr/bin` folder) and comment out the following line:

```
apt-get -y -q purge firefox-locale-en libreoffice-help-en-*
```